# The inequality $K_X^n\leq (-n-1)^n \chi (\mathscr{O}_X)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective manifold of dimension $n$ with $K_X$ ample. Does the inequality
$$K_X^n\leq (-n-1)^n \chi (\mathscr{O}_X)$$ hold? For $n=2$ or 3 it is
equivalent to the Miyaoka-Yau inequality, but this is no longer true  in higher dimension.

I am a bit suspicious because the analogous inequality $(-K_X)^n\leq (n+1)^n$ for Fano manifolds  is true for $n=2$ or 3, but  false as soon as $n\geq 4$. It would be nice to find a counter-example in the  $K$ ample case.

Comment: Two questions that might not be totally pointless: (1) Is the inequality necessarily satisfied in each dimension by ball quotients? (2) What is the Fano counterexample?

Comment: @Will Sawin: Answer to 1): Yes. This follows from Hirzebruch's proportionality principle: the ratio $K^n/\chi (\mathscr{O})$ is the same for a quotient of the ball and for its compact dual, the projective space — so it is $K_{\mathbb{P}^n}^n=(-n-1)^n$.

Comment: Answer to 2): The counter-example (due to Batyrev) is $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}\oplus \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(n-1))$. It has $(-K)^n=\dfrac{(2n-1)^n-1}{n-1} $. I found it in [this  Bourbaki talk](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/uploads/olivier.debarre/827.pdf) of O. Debarre.